# How do I access outer class variables in inner class(PyQt)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

*It is not a duplicate! I didn't want to make title really long, so it's short version may seem as a duplicate. The problem is a little bit bigger than in the title.*

**Environment:** I'm trying to build painting app using PyQt5 and Qt-Designer. I've got three files in my project: **main.py**, **slider.py**, **ui.py**(UI from Qt-Designer generated by pyuic).

**What do I need:** I need to change **App**'s brush size(self.variable) every time **Slider** value changes.

**The problem itself:** App Class inherits Ui_MainWindow Class from the file that I can't edit(it is generated every time). Ui_MainWindow sets Slider Class as its attribute. So basically Slider is App's attribute, and I need to change App's variable "canvas" while being in Slider Class.

I don't know how to access outer class variable in inner class method. Especially when I can't edit ui.py, so I could call Slider(self) instead of Slider(self.sidebar).

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from ui import Ui_MainWindow


class App(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    example = App()
    example.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

**slider.py**

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from functools import partial
import inspect

class Slider(QSlider):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.valueChanged.connect(self.valueChange)
        self.setMinimum(8)
        self.setMaximum(64)
        self.setTickInterval(8)

    def valueChange(self):
        pass
        # Here I need to change App.canvas, have no idea how to do it
```

**ui.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(912, 715)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.sidebar = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.sidebar.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(388, 0))
        self.sidebar.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.sidebar.setObjectName("sidebar")
        self.clearButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.sidebar)
        self.clearButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 91, 41))
        self.clearButton.setObjectName("clearButton")
        # This is where Slider is called
        # The file is generated so I can't edit it
        self.brushSizeSlider = Slider(self.sidebar)
        # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        self.brushSizeSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 160, 22))
        self.brushSizeSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.brushSizeSlider.setObjectName("brushSizeSlider")
        self.brushSizeLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.sidebar)
        self.brushSizeLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 101, 16))
        self.brushSizeLabel.setObjectName("brushSizeLabel")
        self.brushColorDial = QtWidgets.QDial(self.sidebar)
        self.brushColorDial.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 50, 64))
        self.brushColorDial.setObjectName("brushColorDial")
        self.brushColorLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.sidebar)
        self.brushColorLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 160, 101, 16))
        self.brushColorLabel.setObjectName("brushColorLabel")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.sidebar)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.centralwidget)
        self.canvas.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 500))
        self.canvas.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(5000, 5000))
        self.canvas.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 500))
        self.canvas.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.canvas.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.canvas.setStyleSheet("canvas{background-color: rgb(70, 70, 50);}")
        self.canvas.setObjectName("canvas")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.clearButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clear canvas"))
        self.brushSizeLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Current brush size:"))
        self.brushColorLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Current brush color:"))

from canvas import Canvas
from slider import Slider
```

Comment: The slot that changes the brush should be in the `App` class. Then in `App.__init__` you can do `self.brushSizeSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.valueChangeSlot)`. You probably don't need the `Slider` class at all.

Comment: @ekhumoro, thanks a lot, it helped! I have one more question if you don't mind: when I change width of pen and draw again, it redraws old lines with new width. Is there a way to prevent it? Here is my code for drawing widget: https://ideone.com/nE2jkq

Comment: Please ask a new question showing the relevant code, etc.

Comment: @ekhumoro, ok. I'll ask it later(question time interval limit). Thanks a lot anyways!